# Como cortar texto de string em python, delimitando a substring inicial para a posição final?

Tags: python, python-3.x, delphi

Eu gostaria de saber e entender como retornar o recorte em texto com offset. Eu sou um iniciante em python e atualmente estou em um projeto para migrar de delphi para python e tem algumas coisas que estou aprendendo ainda. Eu tenho uma função que preciso passar para python, mas estou andando em círculos.

Eu tenho uma função que lida com strings, que dá o que está entre o começo e o fim de um dado texto, respeitando o offset e retornando offset inclusive. # // Retorna o resultado do corte no texto offset. Eu vi que o find() do python funciona da mesma forma que o posEx() do Delphi. (Eu não sei se minha função python estaria certa)Mas gostaria de saber qual o funcionamento certo do Find().

#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa Marcos, tudo bom. Cara pelo que entendi você está precisando de uma função para fazer cortes em textos certos, onde você passa o texto a posição inicial e a quantidade de caracteres apartor dessa posição. Se for isso eu escrevi um código python que pode ser útil.

```py
def split_text(obj, substring = None, start = 0, qtd = None):
    '''
    Função para corte de string.
    Você pode passar apenas o objeto de texto sem especificar nada.
    isso retornará seu objeto por inteiro.
    Agora quando o parâmetro qtd for passado sem
    o parametro start ser passado, retorna uma string na 
 quantidade informada.

    Mode de uso.
    passando apenas obj e qtd
    split_text('Seu texto completo aqui', qtd=20)
    sera retornado 20 caracteries apartir do começo da str

    split_text('seu texto aqui',start=16,qtd=7)
    retorma uma string de 7 caracteres começando na pos 
    16 

    slipt_text('seu texto aqui','texto',qtd=10)
    retorna um string com 10 caracaters apartir da palavra texto

    Lembramdo quando voce passar uma substring não passe o parametro start.
    '''

    qtd = len(obj) if qtd is None else qtd

    if substring:
        inicio = obj.find(substring)
        return obj[inicio:inicio+qtd]
    elif not substring:
        return obj[start:start+qtd]
```

Veja se isso te ajuda , caso contrário poste o que deu errado ou como podemos ajudar de outra maneira.

Comment: Eai Robson blz? cara isso vai me ajudar bastante pois a lógica envolvida é a mesma! ,e eu buscava por uma explicação assim! para que pudesse me clarear a mente.

Comment: Ah e respondendo sua pergunta sobre o método find(), ele encontra a primeira ocorrência de uma substring, retornando o primeiro índice da ocorrência. Exemplo:``` texto = 'esse meu texto é muito bom esse' text.find('texto') #  >>>4 pois a ocorrência texto começa na posição 4 do elemento ``` Você também pode passar offset para ela: ``` texto.find('esse',5) # >>>27 pq é a primeira ocorrência apartir da posição 5. ``` E você também pode delimitar apenas um bloco passando mais um parâmetro como posição final. ```texto.find('muito',5,26)```

Comment: Que bom que ajudou, caso precise que explica mais o código, só avisar. Mais deixei bem detalhado no comentário no código, e o nível de python usado é bem básico. Se ajudou você peço que marca a pergunta como resolvido, abaixo da opção vote ao lado da resposta.

Comment: Olha uma coisa que dá pra melhorar no código, é poder passar todos os argumentos, o que está faltando implementar é, quando passar uma substring, Você poder passar o parâmetro start, é com isso buscar a substring apartir da posição start e então apartir disso trazer a quantidade de caracteres passada pelo que, ficaria mais completa e é bem simples de fazer, se você quiser vou deixar pra vc tentar implementar e treinar um pouco mais de python também. Abraços.

Answer (score 0):

## Slicing em python

Python tem uma feature muito interessante e fácil de usar chamada "slicing" que pode ser util para obter sub-string a partir de strings, antes de trabalhar diretamente com as strings, vamos ver como isso funciona.

Em python, strings são sequencias do tipo array (ou lista) de caracteres, com algumas diferenças, mas em muitos aspectos pode-se trabalhar com esses objetos como se fossem listas.

A partir dessa informação, podemos usar funcionalidade de *slicing* em nossas strings. Vamos a um exemplo com uma lista.

```
lst = [1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# Fazendo um slicing
>>> lst[5]
6

# Mais um slicing
>>> lst[4:7]
[5, 6, 7]
```

Veja que o slicing nos devolve uma parte da lista (um subset), através de dois argumentos que especificam a posição inicial e final que queremos obter da mesma:

**Syntax: lista[inicio:fim:passo]**

Agora vamos ver como funciona com strings: Digamos que temos a seguinte string, `"Se a implementação é difícl de explicar, é uma ideia ruim"` (do [zen do python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)), vamos fazer alguns *slices* nela

```
# Não nomei somente como "str", o python deixa mas vc sobrepoe o objeto embutido
>>> str1 = "Se a implementação é difícl de explicar, é uma ideia ruim"

# Recortando a palavra "implementação"
>>> str1[5:18]
'implementação'

# Recortando a palavra "Explicar"
>>> str1[31:39]
'explicar'

# Recortando a partir da posicção 1, até o final de 2 em 2 caracteres
>>> str1[1::2]
'eaipeetçoédfc eepia,éuaieari'

# Invertendo a string
>>> str1[::-1]
'miur aiedi amu é ,racilpxe ed lcífid é oãçatnemelpmi a eS'
```

Explicando a sintaxe:

```
s[pos1:pos2]  # Itens a partir de pos1 até pos2-1
s[pos1:]      # Itens a partir de pos1 até o final da string
s[:pos2]      # Itens a partir do inicio da string até pos2-1
s[:]          # Uma copia inteira da string
```

Em todas as opcoes acima pode-se utilizar também o argumento `passo`:

```
s[pos1:pos2:passo]
```

Como `pos2` representa o primeiro elemento que não será selecionado pela operação de slicing, os numero de elementos selecionados será a diferença entre `pos1` e `pos2`, se o número de `passo` for o *default* que é `1`

**Número negativo para `pos1` ou `pos2`:**
Essa é uma *feature* interessante que permite que a contagem seja feita a partir do final da string/list/array ao invés do inicio:

```
s[-1]    # O último item
s[-5:]   # Os últimos cinco itens
s[:-5]   # Tudo, menos os últimos cinco itens
```

**Número negativo para o `passo`:**
Com números negativos atribuido ao `passo` obtem-se o resultado de forma reversa:

```
s[::-1]    # Todos os itens de forma inversa
s[1::-1]   # Os dois primeiros itens de forma inversa
s[:-5:-1]  # Os últimos quatro ítens de forma reversa
s[-5::-1]  # Todos os itens de forma reversa, exceto os cinco últimos
```